# MeteorJS Alternatives: Latency Compensation Frameworks and Libraries?

Tags: meteor, javascript, web-frameworks

**Effort:**
I am building a word game based on a chat web-client where I need to make a server call on input chat text to validate it before broadcasting on the chat.

I am aware of [Meteor](http://meteor.com) providing latency compensation out of the box. But given its still in "early preview" makes me seek other alternatives.

**What I tried:**
Unfortunately my web search for "latency compensation framework library" doesn't yield anything other than Meteor (including non-personalized results).

**Question:** Are there any other alternatives that provide latency compensation -or- can make the job easier? I am hoping other developers might have encountered something useful/relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RethinkDB [uses](https://rethinkdb.com/blog/realtime-web/) term 'latency compensation'.
I've also tried to gather [per-feature alternatives to Meteor](http://git.io/vCFVb)

Answer (score 6):

Although Meteor is in 'early preview', its code is very close production ready and a lot of startups and other early adopters are using it for production-level code. You aren't going to find anything that gives you wings like Meteor because **no such alternative exists**.

As a hardcore Meteor convert and someone who's used many other frameworks, I recommend you to just try Meteor out. As they say, it only takes a weekend for you to build an app in Meteor and decide whether it's right for you.

Having said that, I will attempt to answer the question and list the distant-second alternatives to Meteor that you probably won't want to use:

- [Derby](http://derbyjs.com/)
- [Sails](http://sailsjs.org/)

What you're seeing right now in the various real-time full-stack Javascript web frameworks is the future of Web development, cutting down dozens of people and thousands of man-hours of work needed to develop a software project. There are some fast boats sailing that are leaving server-side rendering behind, and you should probably just get in one of them and get going.

Comment: Well said, its hard sometimes to get people to realise how quickly things are changing, and what the User expectations are for modern web apps.

Answer (score 0):

Meteor is a really cool framework. you can build the complex  data driven application very easily using meteor.
But, this framework currently supports only the `MongoDB` as back-end database.
I have recently created full stack framework called [Nooljs](http://nooljs.github.io/nooljs/)  which is similar to the Meteor. Now I have open sourced it.  It support all the database connections including `MySql`, ms-sql, and  `MongoDB`. The complex data driven application can be created easily  using this framework. 
This has been developed using well known existing framework such as Angularjs, Node, express-js, and socket-io.
Easy to build complex data driven JavaScript applications with minimum coding.
Support multiple data connections suck as Ms-sql, MySQL, PostgreSQL, and Mondodb.

- Real time framework build top of Express-js and Socket-io
- The client side is powered by the Angularjs.
- The layout can be build using the Angularjs tags and elements.
- Modularized layout to simplify the complex web pages.
- Can be mixed both Express-js and Socket-io